# MS Word 2013 | Create custom Field Code

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I have a document in which I make heavy use of references to tables, graphs etc. like so: `(see Table 25, page 236)`. This is a piece of text with two fields in it.

Now, the Create a Cross-Reference functionality only lets me add one field at a time and the rest of the text, i.e. `see` and `, page`, I have to add by hand. If I wanted to change `page` to `p.`, I'd have to run a smart Replace command.

Is there a way to create my own field, which would produce the above output, thereby guaranteeing its consistent layout throughout the document?

I know I'll most likely have to use VBA but that doesn't avert me, on the contrary. But the only idea that I have now is to make a macro that would just add a string like `(see Table 25, page 236)` whenever I call it. But I want to be able to change, say, `page` to `p.` in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this but as you rightly guessed you will need to use VBA. You can use Custom Document Properties as placeholders and then use some VBA code to parse the field code and set those properties to whatever you want using the SetProperty method.

It is then up to you whether the VBA is triggered by opening the file or whether you add a menu item to do that.

Read [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx) for more details about getting and setting document properties.

Comment: So, in my example with `(see Table 25, page 236)`, what values would these Custom Document Properties actually hold? I think one Property would hold `see ` and the other `, page ` but then if I wanted to insert a reference to a table, I'd have to insert 4 fields, which would print: 1) `see `, 2) `Table 25`, 3) `, page `, 4) `236` (which is a reference to the same bookmark as in no. 1). Is there any way to put these four fields into one field?